# Migrating custom Tabs from Demo account to production account

Tags: docusignapi

We are migrating our DocuSign Demo account to production. For this- we downloaded all templates from demo account as xml and uploaded same on production account- Which is working fine.

We have approx 200 custom Tabs created for these templates in demo account, is there any way to download/migrate these Custom Tabs to production account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, unfortunately there is no way of completely automating this; however there's one important thing I'll mention here which implies that you might not even have to migrate any of your Custom Tags, and I also have a manual workaround that will save you time if you do indeed want to migrate them.

First off, if you're using Custom Tags in templates only then you probably don't need to migrate *any* tags. The custom tag definition is embedded within the xml of your templates, so the system should have enough information to display and utilize them in your envelopes as expected.

However if you're using them in other places and/or you want them to show in the Custom Tag area of your production account preferences in order to modify them, then you can do the following to help save some time:

1. Create and save a template in demo that has all the Custom Tags that you want to migrate.
2. Migrate the template by downloading the template xml from demo and uploading into your production account.
3. Open the template and for each tab you want migrated double click and select **Save As Custom**.   This will in turn add the Custom Tag to your production account.

Unfortunately that's the quickest way to migrate Custom Tags currently, but as mentioned you might not have to do this at all - your envelopes still have all the info they need to function properly in production.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Will follow your advice for moving forward.